# How to iterate through a struct's fields?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, struct

I have a simple struct that looks like this:

```
public struct GridNeighbours
{
    public static Vector2Int North = new Vector2Int(0, 1);
    public static Vector2Int South = new Vector2Int(0, -1);
    public static Vector2Int East = new Vector2Int(1, 0);
    public static Vector2Int West = new Vector2Int(-1, 0);
}
```

Is there a way to "iterate" through each of these fields somehow with a `for` loop? Do structs by chance index their fields or something? It would make my code a lot cleaner if it was possible but I am not sure how to make it iterative.

**Edit**: due to this being used in a hot path in a game, is there a way to rewrite this so i can avoid reflection ?

This is not a duplicate since i need an alternative approach to **avoid** reflection.

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613782/iterating-through-struct-members

Comment: Hmm is there any way to re-write it so i don't have to use reflection? This is used in a game and reflection is a bit performant heavy im told. Which is no good for pathfinding etc.

Comment: You could use reflection initially to get the structs, but compile the getter so future calls are less expensive.

Comment: @CoderofCode see my edit before flagging duplicate >.>

Comment: @ParrishHusband what do you mean ?

Comment: Before diving into that, can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Take a look at Jon Skeet's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20522251/6326344 He explained how to loop through object properties without reflection. You can use this approach.

Comment: You can set up dictionary with key value and then loop through. But again it is not clear at all what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I am doing pathfinding and have to check neighbour tiles and it was getting a pain having to hand write each vector for each neighbour so i wanted to store them and iterate them from some static location

Comment: So this is an A* implementation right?

Comment: This is to get the tile mask to draw the correct image sprite, but pathfinding will also be a factor

Comment: You have a custom grid item class right?  Can you post that?  I think what you really want is a `Neighbors` property on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public struct GridNeighbours {

    public enum Cardinal { North, East, South, West }

    public static Vector2Int[] Neighbours = { new Vector2Int(0, 1), new Vector2Int(1, 0), new Vector2Int(0, -1), new Vector2Int(-1, 0) };

    public Vector2Int this[Cardinal dirn] {
        get { return this[(int)dirn]; }
        set { this[(int)dirn] = value; }
    }

    public Vector2Int this[int dirn] {
        get { return Neighbours[dirn]; }
        set { Neighbours[dirn] = value; }
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
var cell = new GridNeighbours();
var NorthNeighbour = cell[Cardinal.North];
Assert(cell[Cardinal.South] == cell[2]); // This is true!
```

===

Alternatively, if you want "direct" properties:

```
public struct GridNeighbours {
    public enum Cardinal { North, East, South, West }

    public static Vector2Int[] Neighbours = { new Vector2Int(0, 1), new Vector2Int(1, 0), new Vector2Int(0, -1), new Vector2Int(-1, 0) };

    public static Vector2Int North { get { return Neighbours[0]; } set { Neighbours[0] = value; } }
    public static Vector2Int East { get { return Neighbours[1]; } set { Neighbours[1] = value; } }
    public static Vector2Int South { get { return Neighbours[2]; } set { Neighbours[2] = value; } }
    public static Vector2Int West { get { return Neighbours[3]; } set { Neighbours[3] = value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the possible values in the struct will not be known in the compile-time, then you can try using Reflection. More specifically, using `Type.GetFields()` or `Type.GetProperties()`.

Example:

```
Type structType = typeof(GridNeighbours); 
FieldInfo[] fields = structType.GetFields(); 
Foreach(FieldInfo field in fields) 
{
    //Do something
}
```

But keeping the fact in mind that there will always be four directions, why a simple `GridNeighboursInstance.North` is not a preference for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without using reflection I don't think you can do it given the signature you have there.

What you **could** do is to setup an indexer on the struct that would allow you to loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a dynamic way so I can suggest you to use a static way! When you have only those four members and you want to iterate over them you need to implement an `AsEnumerable` method inside your `struct` something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Vector2Int> AsEnumerable()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                yield return North;
                break;
            case 2:
                yield return South;
                break;
            case 3:
                yield return East;
                break;
            case 4:
                yield return West;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think there are some better way, But HTH ;).

Comment: A static `Dictionary<int,Vector2Int>` would likely be quicker.  Although with only 4 items I'm starting to wonder if the overhead of the indexing would nullify the efficiency.